# Generate an n bit random number in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I can easily generate a random number of width 32 bits in Verilog using `$random`. Is there a way to generate a random number of exactly `n` bits (say `n = 70`)?

I guess I could concatenate many 32-bits random numbers, and then restrict down to the required number of bits, but that seems like a hack.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable hack to me, given the Verilog simulator will need to actually do its calculations using the underlying machine architecture, which probably deals with 32 or 64 bit words rather than single bits at a time.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011576/generating-random-numbers-in-verilog

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are able to use SystemVerilog, you can randomize a number of any width.  Either declare it as `rand` within a class, or use `std::randomize`.  Here is a simple example:

```
module top;

  bit[69:0] vec;

  initial begin
    assert(std::randomize(vec));
    $display("vec = %070b", vec);
  end

endmodule
```

If you need to stick to plain old Verilog, I think the hack you suggested is the best, simplest, and possibly the only choice. I don't think there is anything in the language to help, since `$random` returns a 32-bit number.

If you simply want to avoid declaring new variables and explicitly concatenating them, you could do something like this.

```
vec[31:0]  = $random;
vec[63:32] = $random;
vec[69:64] = $random;
```